# SQL IN Operator in Redis by FT.Search/FT.Aggregate

Tags: redis, ft.search

I have a query that I need to translate from **sql** to **redis**.
here is an example of this request

```
id IN(1,2,4,6)
```

My schema look's like this:

```
FT.CREATE log         // Index name
  ON HASH             // Indicates the type of data to index
    PREFIX 1 "log:"   // Tells the index which keys it should index
  SCHEMA
    id        NUMERIC SORTABLE
    finfo     TEXT NOINDEX
```

https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/reference/query_syntax/

I saw a couple of examples on a site like this:

```
@id:(1|2|4|6)
```

but it doesn't work

I want to use a **FILTER** to send parameters to **FT.** module.
something like that

```
FILTER "@id:(1|2|4|6)"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with NUMERIC fields you can try range queries, something like:

```
FT.SEARCH log "@id:[1 6]"
```

depending the format of your ID field it will be better use `TAG` instead `NUMERIC` allowing you to use prefix search like:

```
FT.SEARCH log "@id:{11*}"
```

or using OR operator "pipe" for multiple values such as:

```
FT.SEARCH log "id:{111 | 222 | 333 | 444}" DIALECT 3
```

more info at the documentation https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/reference/query_syntax/

Comment: Agree. TAG is probably the way to go here. Unless you plan to do math or range queries on the field, there's really no reason to use NUMERIC. I almost always use TAGs for IDs.

Comment: if I need to search both in the range and just in the list of values, then it is better to use 2 variables (the type of one will be the number of the second TAG)?